# Does DB::raw affect when uploaded on server?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, amazon-web-services, laravel-4

Currently using this code to fetch data on mysql and its working on my localhost but when I uploaded it on our AWS server it stop sorting?

```
$raw = "( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('$lat') ) * cos( radians( '$lat' ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians('$lon') ) + sin( radians('$lat') ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance";
$stores = DB::table('stores')
    ->select('storename', 'id', 'photo', 'address', DB::raw($raw))
    ->orderBy('distance')
    ->where('domain', $domain->appEnv)
    ->take(25)
    ->get();
```

Is there something that is being affected when I uploaded on AWS?

Note that our DB is on a different server for RDS

Comment: Do you use same DB engine for your local and AWS?

Comment: use   ->where('domain',$domain->appEnv) before ->orderBy('distance')

Comment: I don't think the order of function calls has an effect on the end query.
@TheBlurr chances are there is an environment difference between your production and local databases. What engine are you using in both cases?

Comment: @EdwardSamuel Im using my local db

Comment: @user4621032 no difference

Comment: What do I mean: what is your DB engine in local and AWS? SQLite/MySQL/PostgreSQL/etc?

Comment: @EdwardSamuel locally im using mySQL and on production im using MariaDB

Comment: @SArnab locally im using mySQL and on production im using MariaDB

Comment: I don't have any expertise in MariaDB, but I'm willing to bet that there's differences in how the two process SQL. Perhaps the alias you are creating does not apply to an "ORDER BY" clause in MariaDB? A DB::raw() for the ORDER BY might be worth a shot as well.

Comment: @SArnab I tried to this but it just a syntax error`$stores = DB::table('stores')->select('storename','id','photo','address',DB::raw("( 3959 * acos( cos( radians($lat) ) * cos( radians( $lat ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians($lon) ) + sin( radians($lat) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance ORDER BY distance DESC"))->where('domain',$domain->appEnv)->take(25)->get();`

Comment: @SArnab I think DB engine is not a factor because they are both innoDB am I right?

Comment: No I meant add a DB:raw() statement for the order by. so ->orderBy(DB::raw("distance")). The DB engine itself does not matter here, but the server might (MySQL vs MariaDB).

Comment: @SArnab still not working on server side

Comment: I doubt that that raw query works at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should set data binding for variables that are passed to query.

```
->setBindings([$lat,....])
->get();
```

In your query you shold replace these variables with ? 
and add these variables to setBinding array in the order as you use.